# jQuery change input value on product page that will carry over to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using some jQuery to set the value of a specific select option; I'm trying to make it so if the user selects a certain option they have to buy the set quantity (10 in this case). I'm using `val()`, which sets it, but when I add the product to the cart, the cart page only shows 1. Is there a different jQuery function I should use, or does what I want to accomplish involve much more code?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form').on('change', '#purchase', function(){
        if($(this).val()=="Table of 10") {
            $('input[type="number"]').val("10").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: could you add the html and change it into a runnable code snippet?

Comment: @Jester [here](http://sokiusvente2016.org/gala-tickets/testing/) is my test page is the functionality set up already. Choose the 'table of 10' option, add to cart, go to cart, and you'll see the quantity is 1 instead of 10.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to debug with all the wordpress/woocommerce code around,
I think i've found the problem though.

You're not only changing the value to 10 but you're also disabling the element which prevents it from being submitted. instead of disabling you should make it readonly:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form').on('change', '#purchase', function(){
        if($(this).val()=="Table of 10") {
            $('input[type="number"]').val("10").prop('readonly', true);
        }
    });
});
```

BEWARE! this does prevents most users from entering less but someone experienced with code can inspect the code, remove the readonly or disable tag and just change the value. you have to check for invalid values server side.

Comment: Hmm I am still getting '1' quantity on the cart page with `readonly`

Comment: if i inspect the code it's still disabled after i change the option to table of 10. if i manually change it to readonly and then submit it works for me. try inspecting the element after you applied your change whether it really is executed correctly or maybe some other woocommerce code is still disabling it.